# Rails Job Generator is not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line, jobs, rails-activejob

I want to create a job which will subscribe my users on mailchimp. But when i run `rails generate job subscribe_user_to_mailing_list` command, i got this message

**Could not find generator job.**

my rails version is 4.0.0

**SOLUTION:**
I just found a solution of this problem so i am posting the solution here. May be it should help someone else.

Add this `gem 'activejob_backport'` in your Gemfile and run `bundle install`.

Now create a new file as **config/initializers/active_job.rb**

`ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :inline`

Now run `rails g`. The job generator will be there now.

Comment: Did you tried `rails g` to see if generator exist?

Comment: yes the generator doesn't exist there :(
now what is the solution for that ?

Comment: I answered it below.

Comment: Did I answer your question below?

Comment: sorry that answer is not worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The Active Job framework was introduced in Rails v4.2, so you need to update your rails version in order to use it:

Edit your Gemfile to include

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
```

and then run

```
bundle update
```

Answer (score -1):

Rails Active Job uses [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq), [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque/) or [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) to manage jobs. Add and install what gem you want of those three. Here are some tutorial that I found best for you. [Getting Started With Active Job](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/getting-started-with-active-job), [It's Time For Active Job](http://www.jetthoughts.com/blog/tech/2015/04/17/time-for-active-job.html) and [Background Jobs in Rails 4.2 with Active Job](http://ryanselk.com/2014/09/25/using-background-jobs-in-rails-42-with-active-job/)